# batchedgemm source code?

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, blas

I have a special sort of problem.

I have some research code that I have developed on my macbook using CUDA 4.1, especially using `batchedgemm`. I now have to run it on a cluster of gpu's that I have loaned from another institution.

My problem is that the Cluster only has CUDA 4.0 installed, and they are reluctant to upgrade fast.

Does anyone know if I can get the source for batchedgemm somewhere and compile it to work under 4.0?

I've writen my own kernel for doing batched multiplications, but it performes an order of about 10 slower than the library one - I would like to stand on the shoulders of great men instead of on their toes.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the reluctance to quickly upgrade a production cluster.  Many clusters use a module system which means multiple versions of the CUDA toolkit can coexist.  The driver, however, needs to be upgraded to a version that supports the latest CUDA in use.  This is why they would be reluctant because they would need to test their users' production codes and applications to avoid regression or failure.

Since CUBLAS is not open source, I recommend you try to develop your code on a separate machine and if you get a large speed up from batching, present that to the administrators as a reason to upgrade.